# On doing BufferedReader.readLine() : Unexpected end of ZILB input stream

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, apache-commons-vfs

I am trying to read one line at a time using bufferedReader like following

```
 BufferedReader.readLine()
```

and I am getting the following stack trace.

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:240)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorInputStream.read(MonitorInputStream.java:74)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
```

I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Well it *sounds* like you've got an invalid compressed file...

Comment: what kind of file are you reading from ?

Comment: I am reading a Zipped CSV file. No the first 4-5 times it goes well . But then suddenly this exception starts coming and once it comes thereafter it's start coming everytime.

Comment: And I would have understood if the exception would been coming for the same line. The lines which the exceptions are coming are somehow random.

Comment: can you open / unzip that zip file manually? (i.e. using unzip command in Linux or in Windows 7zip, WinRar etc.)

Comment: ya i can do .There are no errors.

Comment: Wait, why are you reading a zip file, *line by line*?

Comment: No i am reading the CSV file inside the zip file line by line.

Comment: But that CSV is compressed... So what do you get from reading it line by line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5314/discussion-between-yair-and-user882196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, you can try the example from [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm) for reading entries from inside a zip file. I've checked it and it works great. No need for VFS, just use java.util.